# Замечательный, знаменитый и известный вопросы

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация

> ```
> Замеченный вопрос   Вопрос с 1000 просмотров     13.6k награжден
> Известный вопрос    Вопрос просмотрен 2500 раз    3.7k награжден
> Знаменитый вопрос   Вопрос с 10000 просмотров      262 награжден
> ```

Думаю, логично вторую формулировку сделать такой же, как первая и третья.

> ```
> Хороший ответ    Ответ с рейтингом 10 или более баллов   537 награжден
> Отличный ответ   Ответ с рейтинг 25 или более баллов      38 награжден
> Лучший ответ     Ответ с рейтингом 100 и более баллов      1 награжден
> ```

И здесь с серебряным вариантом что-то не то...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Исправил в transifex.

Comment: Описание `известного вопроса` по-прежнему отличается от двух аналогичных. А `отличный ответ` поменялся - значит дело не в кешировании чего-нибудь?

Comment: Хм, странно. Сейчас перепроверю.

Comment: У меня «отличный ответ» выглядит по-старому.

Comment: Ай.. Я не прав - перепутал ответ с вопросом. Значит, ждём обновления кэша.

Comment: `* с 2500 просмотров` - "просмотров" или "просмотрами"?

Comment: Лучший ответ: `и более`, остальные 5 мест `или более`.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Не уверен, спрошу-ка в чате.

Comment: @Qwertiy: А по поводу «или более» — да, «и более» смотрится намного лучше, сейчас поправлю.

Comment: "Исправил в Transifex" не означает, что изменения были залиты в боевую базу. Это должен вручную сделать Nicolas.